# How to tell thunar to stop using my device?

Tags: usb-drive, xubuntu, thunar

When I do

```
sudo umount /media/KINGSTON
```

I got

```
umount: /media/KINGSTON: device is busy.
```

By using

```
fuser -c /media/KINGSTON
```

And

```
cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

I found that the process is thunar--deamon.  I closed all file manager windows.  When I try to umount it by right cliking on the desktop, it also gave an error :

```
An application is preventing the volume "KINGSTON" from being unmounted
```

I am affraid that killing Thunar is going to impact other process running in other terminal.  How can I tell it that I don't need this usb key anymore so it stop using it?

Comment: If nothing is writing to the usb stick and you're out of other ideas, unplug it.

Comment: `sudo fuser -mv /media/KINGSTON` will show the process name (instead of needing to do the separate `cmdline` command).

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the media device is synchronised (there're no outstanding writes), then use the -f switch to umount (force unmount).

From the unmount man page, the -l switch does a "lazy" unmount, which detaches the filesystem now, and cleans up all references later.

```
sudo umount -f /media/KINGSTON
```

or

```
sudo umount -l /media/KINGSTON
```